# Cannot Open Trash from Nautilus

Tags: nautilus, trash

I accidentally deleted all my music files from Rhythmbox. And I want to restore it from the trash. But when I open the Trash in Nautilus, I got error "Aborted (core dumped)" in terminal. Why is it?

I've tried to use trash-cli, but it can only restore file one by one, and I've about 1300 files to restore. Any other idea to restore them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to reinstall nautilus and then open the trash again,

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall nautilus
```

Or

you can install  [PCMan File Manager](http://pcmanfm.sourceforge.net/) to open trash.It was more effective than thunar and nautilus.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I solve it using pcmanfm.

Comment: I can't, because I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: I install pcmanfm, open Trash from pcmanfm, then restore all my files. I think nautilus can't open Trash with too many files inside (CMIIW).